# JFace - How to remove preference property?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I'm wokring with a little JFace preference store where I can add preferences straight forward enough, but have trouble when I want to remove one of the preferences I've put in.

I can't see anything in the APIs that allows for removal. What is the correct way for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using `IPreferenceStore` you call `setToDefault("pref id")` to reset a preference to its default value.

Comment: I'm looking to remove the preference not reset to default value?

Comment: Wait that actually does remove it, thanks greg. The setToDefault name was a bit misleading.

Comment: @seanleroy Eclipse stores only preferences that are not equal to their default values. Thats why _reset_ and _remove_ are the same here.

Answer (score 0):

This is weird !!
I asked this same question 3 days ago in the eclipse JFace forum: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1088245
I only got answers not related to my need.
The answer is that it is not possible. Also you can not set the value or the default of a preference  to `"null"`
In my app ([JMSToolBox](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmstoolbox)), the need is to "cleanup" the file that is backing the `PersistenceStore` as the user may store a lot of "keys/preferences" that may become obsolete at some point in time. I wanted a way to "remove/delete" them from the file to keep the `PreferenceStore` file as compact as possible.
I ended up writing my own version of PreferenceStore that exposes the "remove" method from the internal "Properties" object used by `PreferenceStore`. This class is not designed to fullfill my need.
Code is [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/jmstoolbox/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/org.titou10.jtb.core/src/org/titou10/jtb/config/JTBPreferenceStore.java)